# "Prettier" extension of Swagger UI for website documentation

Tags: rest, swagger-ui, xero-api

we are using swagger.io for documenting our REST API, please can you recommend how to make it even prettier for end-users once it's published on our website documentation subpage?
We want to include some schemas/images and I very like how i.e. this documentation is structured: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/api-overview . Of course we want it to be self-generated from code + some extra description will be added via WYSIWYG.

Many thanks for your advise and have a great day!
P.S.: Sorry for my language, I'm not an engineer/tech guy :)

Answer (score 0):

I work with XeroAPI - the documentation linked is actually in the release process of being generated directly from our OpenAPI spec.

> https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-OpenAPI

We also have our SDK docs auto-generated using the OAS (OpenAPISpec) showing specific code examples for each language SDK we support.

https://xeroapi.github.io/xero-node/accounting/index.html

You can read more about documentation generation from the openapi-generator repo and doing some research on HtmlDocs2.

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/htmlDocs2